# Нужна информация по OCAJP8

Tags: java

Если кто-нибудь недавно проходил эту сертификацию, то поделитесь, пожалуйста, какими ссылками/тренажерами/репозиториями вы пользовались для успешного прохождения тестирования?

Comment: я готовился по этой книге https://www.amazon.com/OCA-Certified-Associate-Programmer-1Z0-808/dp/1118957407. В принципе больше ничего не нужно

Comment: Спасибо, Артем!

Comment: http://enthuware.com  один из лучший ресурсов для тренировки (практические вопросы), но он платный. Почти все знакомые его использовали перед сдачей.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться с этим тренажером!